# How can i use implicit intent but avoid "select an app to handle this intent" screen?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, intentfilter, android-implicit-intent

In my code I want to trigger an implicit intent to open another android library activity.

```
Intent i = new Intent("Shared library", Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/"));
startActivity(i);
```

Lets say few apps contain this same library. If I trigger an implicit intent will the user see the "select an app to handle this intent"?

Or because all the apps contain the same library it will just open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I trigger an implicit intent will the user see the "select an app to handle this intent"?

If the library:

- ...is an AAR
- ...has an `AndroidManifest.xml` file, which...
- ...has an `<activity>` with an `<intent-filter>` that matches your implicit `Intent`

Then any app that incorporates the library and is not blocking that `<activity>` via its own manifest will be a candidate for responding to that implicit `Intent`. If there are 2+ of those apps, normal Android implicit `Intent` resolution occurs:

- If the user set a default for this `Intent` structure on a previous `startActivity()` call, that default activity will be the one that is started
- Otherwise, the user will see a chooser

> Or because all the apps contain the same library it will just open?

No, because Android does not know which app is the one that the user wants.

> How can i use implicit intent but avoid “select an app to handle this intent” screen?

You can't, if the user has not set a default activity. It is up to the user to decide which app's activity should handle that implicit `Intent`.

To put it another way: malware authors would *love* the ability to unilaterally hijack implicit `Intents` and force them all to route to the malware.